# Prevent data from populating into a Google Spreadsheet from Google Forms when it's a duplicate

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a simple Google Form, that is generate through a Google Apps Script and it stores data into a script created Spreadsheet. When a user submits data through the Google Form, I want to check if the email is a duplicate in the Spreadsheet, and if it is, then I want to prevent the insertion. Any guidance on how would I be able to that would be highly appreciated. I believe that `onFormSubmit` on the `FormsApp` runs after the data has been inserted into the Spreadsheet. If that's the case, how would I deal with a duplicate?

Comment: One approach could be to first assess the submitter's email and run it through a `for` loop against the existing list of users (email) who've already submitted the form and then determine whether or not to write values to sheet. Would you mind sharing the original script's code here? That way, we could advise on a solution that fits exactly to your use case.

Comment: @SourabhChoraria I would love to, but it's a project at work, so I'm not allowed to share anything. I understand it would make it simpler. I'll include simplified snippets in a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you have set-up a [destination spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/destination-type) where all responses are stored, there is no way to prevent insertions.
- What you can do is to create a custom spreadsheet where you manually insert the form responses of your choice - based on the [respondent email](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response.html#getRespondentEmail())
- For this, yoou need to create script bound to the Google Form that will retrieve on `onFormSubmit` trigger the latest response, compare the respondent email against the ones from previous responses and based on the result do or do not insert the response into a spreadsheet of your choice.

**Sample code:**

```
function myFunction() {
  var form=FormApp.getActiveForm();
  //set up the collection of emails
  form.setCollectEmail(true);
  var responses=form.getResponses();
  var lastResponse=responses[responses.length-1];
  var lastRespondent=lastResponse.getRespondentEmail();
  var duplicate=false;
  for(var i=0;i<responses.length-1;i++){
    if(responses[i].getRespondentEmail()==lastRespondent){
      duplicate=true;
    }
  }
  if(duplicate==false){
    var mySheet=SpreadsheetApp.openById('SPREADSHEET_OF_YOUR_CHOICE').getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    var items=[];
    for(var j=0;j<lastResponse.getItemResponses().length;j++){
      items.push(lastResponse.getItemResponses()[j].getResponse())
    }
    mySheet.appendRow(items)   
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have set a destination in `Google Drive`. Fine, I can change that if the functionality requires it to happen. I have a question in that case. So when I'm making the form, all I have to do is let Google Forms populate data in its default spreadsheet, and then I create my own Spreadsheet saved separately and manually insert data into it every time like you have demonstrated above. So, is there a way to disable the default automatically created Spreadsheet where the data is stored (I believe Google Forms does create a default spreadsheet which is stored in Google Drive).

Comment: I'll try this out and let you know how it goes. Thanks a lot buddy.

Comment: Whoops, I can't use it unfortunately. I need to use the destination, because a script of mine creates forms dynamically and attaches a Spreadsheet at a `Destination` in `Google Drive`. Since that functionality is crucial, I think this solution might not do it fo rme.

Comment: @HassanAlthaf If you have a set destination where all responses are saved, it does not hinder you from ignoring it and  creating a second spreadsheet where only the non-duplicates are saved. Also, you can change you script that creates forms dynamically.

Comment: The thing is, creation of forms dynamically is an important feature in the spec.

Comment: There is nothing that prevents you incorporate the script in my sample into the one that creates the forms dynamically.

Comment: I understand what you mean. Make a new separate sheet, right?

Comment: So, there'll be two sheets. I get you. I'll try that and update you.

Comment: Yes, exactly, when your script dynamically creates a new form, you can attach to it on creation the script in my answer - you can do so e.g. with the Apps-Script-Api: programmatically attach a script to  new form